# How to select every row to satisfy any rule described in a different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I have a table `numbers`:

| id | n |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 9 |

And I have a table of `rules`:

| rule_type | n |
| --- | --- |
| LT | 2 |
| GT | 7 |
| GT | 9 |
| EQ | 2 |

(LT - less-than, GT - greater-than, EQ - equals).

I want to select every id from `numbers`, that satisfies any rule from table `rules`.

`Expected result`:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 5 |

P.S. I use PostgreSQL 15.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your tables to create this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05c15/3) and wrote a query and tested it.

The following query works :

```
select distinct n.id 
from numbers n 
join rules r ON (
  (r.rule_type = 'LT' and n.n < r.n) or 
  (r.rule_type = 'GT' and n.n > r.n) or 
  (r.rule_type = 'EQ' and n.n = r.n)
);
```

It returns the expected output :

```
id
1
2
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM numbers v
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM rules r
     WHERE (r.rule_type = 'LT' AND v.n < r.n)
        OR (r.rule_type = 'GT' AND v.n > r.n)
        OR (r.rule_type = 'EQ' AND v.n = r.n)
)
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Swofnk2y)